# How to use a Blind SQL-i keyword?

Tags: sql-injection, vulnerability

After scanning my website with uniscan I found a few vulnerabilities. I found this answer [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33741/sql-injection-union-select-and-returning-a-keyword-to-find-exploitable-colum) and tried but it does not return anything except what it should return.

```
Blind SQL Injection:

[+] Vul [Blind SQL-i]: http:/192.168.1.100/browse.html?user_id=10590'+AND+'1'='1     
[+] Keyword: Compassion
```

How to use the keyword in order to inject successfully?

Comment: Do you get a different result with `10590' AND '1'='0`?

Comment: No, i get a different result if i write id=10590 only
`http:/192.168.1.100/browse.html?user_id=10590`

Comment: If `10590' AND '1'='0` and `10590' AND '1'='1` don’t have different results, you’re probably not vulnerable. Or what exactly is the difference in both?

Comment: `user_id=10590` != `user_id=10590'+AND+'1'='1` == `user_id=10590'+AND+'1'='0'` 
does that make the website vulnerable?

Comment: But anyway, what do I have to do with this keyword?

Comment: The expression `'1'='1'` in `10590' AND '1'='1` would make the condition true for each row while `'1'='0'` would be false for each row. If you don’t get a different result, it’s not vulnerable. That `10590` and `10590' AND '1'='1` gives you different results is probably because there is no user with the id `10590' AND '1'='1`.

Comment: Thank you. Consider writing the last commend as an answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the vulnerability scanner tried is to add a condition that is either *true* for all rows (`'1'='1'`, tautology, added with `10590' AND '1'='1`) or *false* for each row (`'1'='0'`, contradiction, added with `10590' AND '1'='1`). If you don’t get a different result for these, it’s probably not vulnerable.

However, that the *user_id* values `10590` and `10590' AND '1'='1` gives you different results is probably because there is no user with the ID `10590' AND '1'='1`.